# Typo in bounty message: “others users”

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, wording, plurals

[image]

The typo is in the phrase “others users,” which should read “other users.”

Comment: Plural engine got greedy.

Comment: Huh. Is a typo that complex of a bug to have fixed?

Comment: If my suspicion that it's a bug in some generic engine that handles plurals is true then yes, it's complex since it will affect other parts of the site. (i.e. might break other, seemingly unrelated, things)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't in any way related to the translation/pluralization engine. Just a run-of-the-mill typo adding an extra `s` where one isn't needed.

It'll be fixed with the next production build. Thanks for the report!